# Can't use jQuery in Joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, joomla

I try to use jQuery on a Joomla site.

For this I have tried to use the very simple example code in the [jQuery UI documentation](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default).

So on my site I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>             
<input class="hasDatepicker" id="datepicker" type="text" />
```

jQuery and jQueryUI should be loaded like I see in the source.

But, it still doesn't work. What is wrong here?

I tried to use `$.noConflict();` but still no luck.

You can see my site here: http://www.schlitteln-berguen.ch/mieten

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check your developer tools, you for instance have an Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function error which can cause bad things to happen.

Comment: you are using `JCaption` and `Tips` in your script ... make sure to include required js files for `JCaption` and `Tips` to work ... because you are getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` which occurs when you donot include required js files in your page and moreover i don't think you are either including jquery and jquery-ui in your page.

Answer (score 1):

Ok just seen by your admin page you're using Joomla 3.x, so by this, I assume you're importing jQuery and jQueryUI correctly. Joomla 3.x by default imports jQuery in **noConflict** mode so I would recommend you use the `jQuery` global scope and pass the `$` through as an alias, like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

Also just to let you know, your template is importing jQuery again. 2 version can cause conflicts so I would suggest if there is an option to remove it in the template parameter, then you do so.